# Move dimension lines away from a polygon

Tags: javascript, three.js, polygon

So I have multiple points which creates a polygon. I have calculated the center point of the polygon and used that to create dimension lines for each side of a polygon. My problem is that some dimension lines don't move to a new position that I calculated. To have a better view here's an image of what I have and what I want to happen.

What I have:

[image]

What I want to achieve:
I added a red circle to the issue I'm having it should move to new point which is the blue lines.

[image]

Here's code snippet:

```js
var viewHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
   var viewWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;

   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
       viewWidth / - 2, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, viewHeight / - 2, 1, 1000);

   camera.translateZ(15);
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   scene.add(camera);

   var points = [
    {
     start: {x: -99.74425000000002, y: 68.61000000000001},
     end: {x: -99.74425000000002, y: -37.87599999999999}
    },
    {
     start: {x: -99.74425000000002, y: -37.87599999999999},
     end: {x: 69.22574999999995, y: -37.87599999999999}
    },
    {
     start: {x: 69.22574999999995, y: -37.87599999999999},
     end: {x: 69.22574999999995, y: -1.2999999999999832}
    },
    {
     start: {x: 69.22574999999995, y: -1.2999999999999832},
     end: {x: 120.02574999999996, y: -1.2999999999999827}
    },
    {
     start: {x: 120.02574999999996, y: -1.2999999999999827},
     end: {x: 120.02574999999996, y: 68.61000000000001}
    },
    {
     start: {x: 120.02574999999996, y: 68.61000000000001},
     end: {x: -99.74425000000002, y: 68.61000000000001}
    }
   ];

   var vertices = [];
   for (var i in points) {
    var line = points[i];
    vertices.push(new THREE.Vector2(line.start.x, line.start.y));
   };

   // build floor
   var floor = buildFloor(vertices);
   scene.add(floor);

   // get center point of floor
   var center = findCentroid(vertices);

   // build dimension lines
   for (var i in points) {
    var line = points[i];

    var lineCenterPoint = findLineCenterPoint(line.start, line.end);
    var degrees = getAngle(center.x, center.y, lineCenterPoint.x, lineCenterPoint.y);
    var radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180;

    var startX = line.start.x;
    var startY = line.start.y;
    var endX = line.end.x;
    var endY = line.end.y;

    if (startY == endY) {
     // horizontal
     // move point y outward to a new point
     var newY = startY + Math.sin(radians) * 20;
     startY = newY;
     endY = newY;

    } else if (startX == endX) {
     // vertical
     // move point x outward to a new point
      var x = startX + Math.cos(radians) * 20;
      startX = x;
      endX = x;
    } else {
     // todo diagonal lines
     // don't know what should be the formula for this
    }

    var from = new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0);
    var to = new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0);

    var direction = to.clone().sub(from);
    var length = direction.length();
    
    var hex = 0x0;
    var arrorGroupHelper = new THREE.Group();
    arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, hex, 1, 10));
    arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.negate(), to, length, hex, 1, 10));
    scene.add(arrorGroupHelper);

    var text = document.createElement('div');
    text.style.position = 'absolute';
    text.style.zIndex = 5;
    text.style.backgroundColor = "ffffff";
    text.innerHTML = length.toFixed(2);

    let interiorCenter = to.clone().add(from).multiplyScalar(0.5);
    let textPos = interiorCenter.project( camera );

    var widthHalf = viewWidth;
    var heightHalf = viewHeight;

    var style = 'translate(-50%,-50%) translate(' + ( textPos.x * widthHalf + widthHalf ) + 'px,' + ( - textPos.y * heightHalf + heightHalf ) + 'px)';
    text.style.transform = style;

    document.getElementById('container').append(text);
   }

   var threejsCanvas = document.getElementById('threejs-canvas');

   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas : threejsCanvas,
    alpha : true
   });

   renderer.autoClear = false;
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   renderer.render( scene, camera );
   
   animate();

   window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   function onWindowResize() {
    var width = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var height = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.left = -width / 2;
    camera.right = width / 2
    camera.top = height / 2;
    camera.bottom = -height / 2;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   }

   function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
   }

   function render() {
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }

   function findLineCenterPoint(a, b) {
       return { x: (b.x - a.x) / 2 + a.x, y: (b.y - a.y) / 2 + a.y }; 
   }

   function findCentroid (arr) {
       var minX, maxX, minY, maxY;
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       {
           var x = arr[i]['x'], y = arr[i]['y'];
           minX = (x < minX || minX == null) ? x : minX;
           maxX = (x > maxX || maxX == null) ? x : maxX;
           minY = (y < minY || minY == null) ? y : minY;
           maxY = (y > maxY || maxY == null) ? y : maxY;
       }
       return {x:(minX + maxX) / 2, y:(minY + maxY) / 2};
   }

   function buildFloor(vertices) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xcccccc,
    });

    var shape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);

    var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return floor;
   }

   function getAngle(originX, originY, targetX, targetY) {
          var dx = originX - targetX;
          var dy = originY - targetY;

          var theta = Math.atan2(-dy, -dx); 
          theta *= 180 / Math.PI;           
          if (theta < 0) theta += 360;   

          return theta;
      }
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
   }
   #threejs-canvas {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
   }
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
   <canvas id="threejs-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Here's my question:

1. How do I move the dimension lines encircled on red on the image above to the new points which is the blue lines.

Thanks. Hope someone could shed a light on this.